# How to handle multiple values within two arguments in python class

Tags: python

I want to create a python class something like this:

class.py

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, email, delay_time=0):
        print email
        print delay_time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyClass()
```

The email argument is mandatory and should be able to contain multiple values and delay_time should be an optional argument. I want to call it like this:

```
python class.py abc@email.com abc1@email.com abc2@email.com 3600
python class.py abc@email.com abc1@email.com
```

I've tried this with docopt, but no luck with that as well. Please suggest.

Comment: This looks more like a code review than a problem. Since the code has multiple issues,  please describe what you want to achieve

Comment: @Pynchia this is what I wanted to achieve - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34607342/2576170

Below xecgr's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script

```
import sys
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, emails, delay_time=0):
        for email in emails:
            print email
        print delay_time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        emails = sys.argv[1:-1]
        delay = sys.argv[-1]
        try:
            delay = int(delay)
        except ValueError:
            emails.append(delay) #there's no delay
            delay=0
        a = MyClass(emails,delay_time=delay)
```

Here's the output

```
$:~/dev/stack$ python class.py abc@email.com abc1@email.com abc2@email.com 3600
abc@email.com
abc1@email.com
abc2@email.com
3600
$:~/dev/stack$ python class.py abc@email.com abc1@email.com
abc@email.com
abc1@email.com
0
```

Comment: Works fine, just one glitch. If you don't specify any value for email at run time, it puts file name (class.py) into variable emails as it's sys.argv[0] that comes within sys.argv[1:-1] 

So one check need to be applied for length of sys.argv just after if __name__ line.

Anyway thanks !

Comment: yep, that's the check for sys.argv Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use this method:

```
email = sys.argv[1]
delay_time= sys.argv[2]
```

Then use the variable as you do wish.

**Edit:** 
Full example (fixed a mistake too):

```
def __init__(self):
    email = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        delay_time= sys.argv[2]
    else:
        delay_time=0
    print email
    print delay_time
```